# get list of all service from a specific app (from manifest)

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I get a list of all services declared in the AndroidManifest.xml from a specific app?

In other words, I've written an app with package "com.example.exampleapp". How can I get a list of all permissions that are previously declared in the manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may help you...

```
    int flags = PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES
            | PackageManager.GET_CONFIGURATIONS
            | PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS
            | PackageManager.GET_GIDS | PackageManager.GET_INSTRUMENTATION
            | PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS
            | PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS | PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS
            | PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS | PackageManager.GET_SERVICES
            | PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES;
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> installedPackages = packageManager
            .getInstalledPackages(flags);
    for (PackageInfo packageInfo : installedPackages) {
        ServiceInfo[] services = packageInfo.services;
        PermissionInfo[] permissions = packageInfo.permissions;
    }
```

and for a particular package...

```
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                "packageName", flags);
        ServiceInfo[] services = packageInfo.services;
        for (ServiceInfo serviceInfo : services) {
            buffer.append(serviceInfo.name + "\n");
        }
        PermissionInfo[] permissions = packageInfo.permissions;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textView.setText(buffer);
```

Comment: How can i write services into a textview?